# Papers on durable queue design with multiple distributed workers

Tags: queues

What's the state of the art for a durable, distributed worker queue on top of a consistent, transactional database (such as SQL)? More concretely, the problem I'm trying to investigate is the following:

- worker picks queue item
- worker starts processing
- worker dies (eg machine reboot)

How can a eg: worker supervisor process ensure that a worker is truly dead and not just eg: slow, GC'ing, stalled, etc? If you pick an item from the DB, and mark it as "processing", how can you be sure the processing process is still live? I know idempotency kinda gives you a free pass but I am looking for eg: some papers around this.

Most of the stuff I see is based on hearbeats, liveness checks and leases, but I'd like something a bit more formal. Are there algorithms or techniques for this case?